# how to reach the row item in listview from onItemCheckedStateChanged in MultiChoiceModeListener

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make row item checked (mean for example change background or whatever indicates is selected) ... this is an example for two element selected and no effect of these:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb8fh.jpg

and here my code :

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    listApps = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.xmlListView);
    listApps.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listApps.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean b) {

            actionMode.setTitle(listApps.getCheckedItemCount() + " Selected Items");

            //******************************************
            // what should i do to reach to row item -_-
            //******************************************

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item_selected, menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a drawable selector and use as a background for each item's layout in a `ListView` to highlight the selected row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/highlight_color" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

Comment: doesn't work because didn't make the item row checked and i want to change background of checked item : 
'''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/yellow" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/aqua" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/fuchsia" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_activated="true" />

</selector>